# How to get tags with custom taxonomy field?

Tags: wordpress

I have added custom taxonomy fields on tags but when I use `get_tags()` it does not return custom field. Right now I am using `get_term_meta()` for custom field but I have 4000 records of tags so when I fire the query to get tags it fires 4000 queries so any way to minimise it or get results in 1 query with `get_tags()`.

Comment: please try this function $terms = get_terms([
    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
    'hide_empty' => false,
]);

Comment: Using this I got all tags ? @developerme

Comment: do you want to display tags ? or custom taxonomy ?

Comment: I need all data. I mean tags with custom field

Comment: Can you elaborate the question a little more with what you have, what is your expected output and your actual output. This will help the users to better understand the situation. Thank you.

Comment: Right now I am getting tags using get_tags() but in output I did not get custom value so I need to fire further query get_term_meta() with term id.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `get_term_by` this will help you to get term meta value  using many different ways.

For more detail check this https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by